# Avoiding subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name, b.name1 FROM a,b 
WHERE a.number NOT IN (SELECT number FROM c) 
AND a.name = b.name1
```

This query takes a very long time to run. I think it is *because of the subquery*.

Is it possible to avoid using subquery in this case?

Comment: Where performance is concerned, you generally need to provide proper DDLs for all relevant tables and the EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0):

Try using join:

```
SELECT a.number, a.name, b.name1 
FROM a join b on a.name = b.name1
left join c on a.number = c.number
WHERE c.number is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as an alternative to get your results.

```
SELECT a.number, a.name, b.name1 
FROM a
JOIN b ON  a.name = b.name1
LEFT JOIN c ON a.number = c.number
WHERE c.number is NULL;
```

You must however check to make sure you have properly defined indexes on your table unless the query will do full table scans on each execution. This will not be noticeable when the data in your table is small, it will start to get slower as your table grows.

You can do an explain on the query to check its execution plan, and optimise accordingly.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT a.number, a.name, b.name1 
FROM a
JOIN b ON  a.name = b.name1
LEFT JOIN c ON a.number = c.number
WHERE c.number is NULL;
```